imul instruction with three operands
I want to use a imul instruction with 3 operands. Is the destination operand the first or last? I searched the web and got contradictory informations.

It depends on the assembly "flavor" you are using:
In Intel syntax the destination operand is the first one.
In AT&T syntax it is the last one.

Thanks, this is it!!!
